# Make the height of two <div> dependable

Tags: html, css

I want  to create two div. have height dependable. If the data in div1 increases,its obvious that the height of div1 will change .then the height of div2 should be change automatically.How can i do this by using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! People usually want to see your code / what you tried so far. By the way the answer to your question is that you can achieve this using display: flex https://jsfiddle.net/zL04jcvc/1/. If you want some more details, just ask and I ll drop in a proper answer. But googling "display: flex" should get you there :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style media="screen">
  .rootdiv {
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .firstdiv, .seconddiv {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
</style>
<div class="rootdiv">
  <div class="firstdiv">First DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst DivFirst Div</div>
  <div class="seconddiv">Second Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have already said that you want solution in css only, but nevertheless if you would like to use jQuery then it may be helpful..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div2').height($('#div1').height());
});
```

```css
#div1, #div2 {width: 50%; background: #666; float: left;}
#div2 {background: #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  Some content here<br /><br />
  Some content here<br /><br />
  Some content here<br /><br />
  Some content here<br /><br />
  Some content here<br /><br />
  Some content here<br /><br />
  Some content here<br /><br />
 </div>
 <div id="div2">
  Few content here
 </div>
```

Here we are making the height of `.div2` equal to the height of `.div1` using jQuery `height()` method.

Comment: This approach backfires on you if you resize your screen.

Comment: We can put it inside `$(window).resize()`.

Comment: Yes that would resolve the resizing issue. But what if div2 is higher than div1. Then your code will cut a part off div2.

Comment: looks pretty good now. The only thing I can come up with to improve your answer is that you should be using id's instead of classes :).